# How do I get my ActivityUnitTestCases to sync with the MessageQueue thread and call my Handler?

Tags: android, junit

I'm writing unit tests for a ListActivity in Android that uses a handler to update a ListAdapter. While my activity works in the Android emulator, running the same code in a unit test doesn't update my adapter: calls to sendEmptyMessage do not call handleMessage in my activity's Handler.

How do I get my ActivityUnitTestCase to sync with the MessageQueue thread and call my Handler?

The code for the Activity is somewhat like this:

```
public class SampleActivity extends ListActivity implements SampleListener {
    List samples = new ArrayList();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample_list);
        listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
    }

    private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // unit test never reaches here
            sharesAdapter = new SampleAdapter(SampleActivity.this, samples);
            setListAdapter(sharesAdapter);
        }
    };

    public void handleSampleUpdate(SampleEvent event) {
        samples.add(event.getSample());
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}
```

The code for my unit test is somewhat like this:

```
public class SampleActivityTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<SampleActivity> {

    public SampleActivityTest() {
        super(SampleActivity.class);
    }

    @MediumTest
    public void test() throws Exception {
        final SampleActivity activity = startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN), null, null);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        activity.handleSampleUpdate(new SampleEvent(this));
        // unit test assert fails on this line:
        assertTrue(listView.getCount() == 1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect but I am not certain that this is because of the use of the instrumentation thread and UIThread not syncing up. So your handler is bound to the thread that creates it. Your handler is created at construction time so it's whatever thread calls the constructor. I don't have the source in front of me, but my guess is that in most cases when the app is running, I am betting it's the UIThead (main) both constructs and calls onCreate() on your activity. But when the unit test is running it is being bound to the Instrumentation Thread which probably constructs your activity and then onCreate is called on the UIThread. Now you are saying in the instrumentation thread, send a message and your thread has no looper associated with it to do anything with it. So it just sits in the queue. Try moving your handler creation to the onCreate(). This should bind your Handler to the main looper and then your async events will be fired from another thread (the instrumentation thread) and the UIThread will gladly reap them from the queue.

While I haven't tested it, this seems like the issue at first glance.